# Can you instantiate the unspecialized version of a template and inherit from it inside the specialization?

Tags: c++, templates, matrix, specialization

I am trying to define a `Vector` as a row/column `Matrix`. `Vector` needs some methods which `Matrix` doesn't have, so I specialized `Matrix`:

```cpp
template<typename T, unsigned N, unsigned M>
struct Matrix {
    T data[N][M];
};

template <typename T, unsigned N>
struct Matrix<T, N, 1> : public Matrix<T, N, 1> {
    T at(unsigned index) {
        return data[index][0];
    }
};

template <typename T, unsigned N>
using Vector = Matrix<T, N, 1>;
```

This code does not compile, because the specialization is a recursive type. The reason I want inheritance here is so that I can include all of the content of `Matrix` into the specialization without copy&paste.

Is there a way that I can instantiate the original `Matrix` and inherit from it? And if there was, would my type become non-recursive?

Another way of solving this problem that comes to mind is to simply `#include` the contents of a regular `Matrix` into both the initial definition and all specializations. But this is far from idiomatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) to disable method. It's necessary to have template method with template argument dependent on the class template parameter.

C++11:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, unsigned N, unsigned M=1>
struct Matrix 
{
    T data[N][M];

    template<typename V = T>
    typename std::enable_if<M == 1, V>::type at(unsigned index)
    {
        return data[index][0];
    }
};

template <typename T, unsigned N>
using Vector = Matrix<T, N, 1>;

int main()
{
    Matrix<int, 2, 3> m;
    Vector<int, 5> v;

    // m.at(0); 
    v.at(1);
}
```

C++14:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, unsigned N, unsigned M=1>
struct Matrix 
{
    T data[N][M];

    template<typename V = T>
    std::enable_if_t<M == 1, V> at(unsigned index)
    {
        return data[index][0];
    }
};

template <typename T, unsigned N>
using Vector = Matrix<T, N, 1>;

int main()
{
    Matrix<int, 2, 3> m;
    Vector<int, 5> v;

    // m.at(0); 
    v.at(1);
}
```

C++20 (Thanks to Jarod42):

```
template<typename T, unsigned N, unsigned M = 1>
struct Matrix 
{
    T data[N][M];

    T at(unsigned index) requires (M == 1)
    {
        return data[index][0];
    }
};

template <typename T, unsigned N>
using Vector = Matrix<T, N, 1>;

int main()
{
    Matrix<int, 2, 3> m;
    Vector<int, 5> v;

    // m.at(0); 
    v.at(1);
}
```

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/uvP12W)

Comment: I never got the SFINAE solution to work myself, so I thought it's impossible. Apparently not. Thanks, I accepted this answer because it's more elegant and `Vector` is literally the same type as `Matrix`, not a derived type.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it:

```
template<typename T, unsigned N, unsigned M>
struct Matrix {
    T data[N][M];
};

template<typename T, unsigned N>
struct MatrixTN : Matrix <T, N, 1> {
    T at(unsigned index) {
        return this->data[index][0];
    }
};

template<typename T, unsigned N>
using Vector = MatrixTN <T, N>;
```

Note that `this->data` is needed to delay evaluation of `data` to the second phase of template lookup.

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bVMQTIJLd24OM0ez)

Comment: In that case there is no difference between `Vector` and `MatrixTN`, so it could just be written as `Vector : Matrix<T, N, 1>`.

Comment: @J.Schultke I guess so.

Answer (score 2):

In C++20, you might use `requires` to discard methods:

```
template<typename T, unsigned N, unsigned M>
struct Matrix {
    T data[N][M];

    T at(unsigned index) requires (M == 1) {
        return data[index][0];
    }
};
```

In previous standard, you might use SFINAE instead.